# An error occured during comment submission

Tags: support

For some reason I cannot add comments on stackoverflow. I tried to answer a question on dba.stackexchange and got an error there too. This is what I see there:
[image]
I tried exiting Firefox, I tried logging out. Did not help. How can I fix it?

Comment: I normally get this with a slightly dodgy internet connection and refreshing the page would be enough.

Comment: I see this every once in a while. Normally it works if I simply try again.